# evento v-on:click en vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde necesito por medio de un click pasar de un `chart` a otro, osea hago click en cualquier lugar del `chart` y necesito que este deje de mostrarse y me muestre el segundo `chart` desde un componente de `vuex`.

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
        <v-flex v-on:click="contador += 1" xs12 sm12 md12 lg12 xl12>
           <chart-component :options="Chart1" :width="'98%'" :height="'500px'" ></chart-component>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex v-if="contador==1" xs12 sm12 md12 lg12 xl12>
           <chart-component :options="Chart2" :width="'98%'" :height="'500px'" ></chart-component>
        </v-flex>
</v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: No estaria entendiendo ni el problema, ni que tiene que ver vuex en esto. que es lo que genera un error o un problema?

Comment: El problema es que necesito mostrar un chart en mi proyecto vuex el cual permita al momento de hacer un click sobre dicho chart ese desaparezca y aparezca otro.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo.. pero no probaste nada? con hacer click sobre el objeto que queres que cambie, y mostrar el otro no alcanza?

Comment: Sí probe utilizar como en el ej q subí un contador donde al hacer click en el componente incremente el contador y cuando esté alcance el valor q tiene el v-if del otro componente q de acciones pero no me dunciono.

Comment: Creo que te estas complicando mucho. Porque no enlazas una variable de verdadero o falso a la directiva show? No seria mas facil? Y en el evento click solo controlas el valor alternativo de la variable y asi se puede mostrar uno y otro en cada click.